# WebStorm 11 code completion for Angular

Tags: angularjs, webstorm, code-completion

I have been using WebStorm for Angular project, I do not get any IDE support
let say defining controller as following

[image]

I have checked that both Angular and AngularTemplates plugins are enabled at `Settings | Plugins` menu.

Comment: project settings and default settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Settings -> Languages and Frameworks -> JavaScript -> Libraries`
click on the download button and try adding the Angular library. Then back to your code right click anywhere inside and the on the use JavaScript Library option select Angular or any other library

[image: adding js libraries to webstorm]

[image: choosing js libraries in webstorm]

Comment: just about to say that - this was the old way of doing it prior to WebStorm 2016.1 - however, maybe the new way is having teeting issues so I suggest going down this road

Comment: it works, I can see the controller related functions, I want to learn more about it,  I choice one of the controller(..) offered then select one of them, but code should be completed with curly brakets, how can I make it possible

Comment: There hasn't been any changes in configuring AngularJS support in WebStorm 2016.1: one should either has an angular.js file in the project or configure angular.d.ts.

Comment: This helped me :)